# why is my global.asax error handler not working?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

i have the following code in my global.ascx and when i click a generate error button the code gets run but seems to fail on the insert error into the DB.

I want the error to be saved to the DB and redirect to default.aspx.

pretty standard stuff.

the error i get is: exe.Message = "Incorrect syntax near 'System'."
(looks like somethign with the SQL objects used in global.asx)

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        StringBuilder theBody = new StringBuilder();        
        theBody.Append("Error Message: " + ex.ToString() + "\n");


        Server.ClearError();

        try
    {
        string sSQL = "INSERT INTO PMISwebErr VALUES ('" + theBody.ToString() + "', GETDATE())";

        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = STAR.Global.GetConnection())
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sSQL, con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }


        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx?Err=sysError");
    }
    catch (Exception exe) {
        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx?Err="+ exe.Message.ToString() );
    }

    }
```

the problem is in the addition of the error message. it has a single quote that breaks the SQL. The code gets this value as a result at this line:

```
theBody.Append("Error Message: " + ex.ToString() + "\n");
```

> sSQL = "INSERT INTO PMISwebErr VALUES
>   ('URL:
>   http://localhost:14854/PMIS/Default.aspx\nReferer:
>   http://localhost:14854/PMIS/Default.aspx\nIP:
>   127.0.0.1\nError Message: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException:
>   Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thr...

that's the actual value from my quick watch, strange to see the ... at the end.

Comment: Is your file actually called `global.ascx`, or is it really `global.asax`?

Comment: What if the error is with the db?

Comment: What is that sql string (are there any unescaped quotes?), do you get any errors (do you see the new error when you remove the redirect?)

Answer (score 3):

You really should use a parameterized insert. I'm sure there are quote issues with the string you're trying to insert, and it's causing the exception.

Here is an example:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210512233418/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml

Comment: +1 - It's not infeasible that some variable in his build up might be injecting single quotes into the string screwing up the execution.

Comment: Not only should you use parameterized SQL here, but you never, ever concatenate SQL as a string like this.  It's a real no-no for security reasons: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

Answer (score 0):

This should really be an `ExecuteNonQuery()` call. `ExecuteScalar()` is intended more for selecting atomic values from aggregates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As [@ScottE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959370/why-is-my-global-asax-error-handler-not-working/4959450#4959450) already expected, you have a problem with quotes. The string is surronded by single quotes, but inside is the text  `Exception of type 'System.Web..` which adds a quote in a place where you don't want it.

The solution? Use parameters and let the driver handle those quotes.